# What exact overhed of RC over tracing GCs is?

Tags: performance, garbage-collection, benchmarking, reference-counting

I had some hot discussions in several chats recently about this matter. I know how GC works under the hood and I know that industry moved from RC-based GCs to tracing GCs. Because of that I'm pretty sure that internally tracing GC should be much more efficient. However, I didn't find any papers about exact numbers.

The question is: does anyone acutally benchmarked what *exact* overhead has RC over regular GC? How does it scales with number of allocated objects and access patterns? Is there patterns when RC has better performance? I searched a lot but I only found some abstract "Tracing GC doesn't have to increment reference counters so it get benefits from it" with no exact numbers or details.

---

If found some articles about the matter, such as https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2005/02/11/resource-management/ and https://www.brainbell.com/tutors/C_Sharp/Performance.htm , but they vaguely cover it.

Comment: This is a very interesting, yet also very wide question. First of all, comparing various GC implementations is almost impossible in any relevant manner. Please refer for example to [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-evaluate-info-you-read-on-garbage-collectors/) from the maintainer of the .NET GC.

Comment: I understand that comparing different languages GC or even different implementation of one GC is error-prone. However, some correlational analysis could be performed to compare GCs to themselves to see what polynomes describe them. Or something. Maybe comparing some really old GCs with their newer counterparts.

Comment: Still, comparing GCs is comparing the whole runtimes. Unless you have replaceable GC like JVM (and .NET recently) does. But again, you could probably replace one tracing GC with another tracing GC because runtime expects that. I'm not aware of any runtime allowing to compare tracing vs RC. Still, [I've asked such question on Twitter](https://twitter.com/konradkokosa/status/1168536149935218689?s=20) if you want to follow.